# combination of mapping and array in solidity. Data Storage Question

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract students{

    struct students{
        string fname;
        string lname;
        string course;      
    }

    mapping (address => students) studentsMappig;

    address[] public studentsArray;

    function setStudents(address _address, string _fname, string _lname,string _course) public{

        var student = studentsMappig[_address];

        student.fname = _fname;
        student.lname = _lname;
        student.course = _course;
        studentsArray.push(_address) -1;

    }

}
```

**Question:** I am pushing _address in studentsArray. This array will store only addresses. where the other data which is mapped will store like fname, lname etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `studentsArray` is and will be solely an array for `address` type values, whereas your `studentsMapping` mapping allows you to access a `students` struct for a specific key (which is an `address`).

Concerning your code :

- You might want to change the struct name from `students` to `Student` as a matter of readability.
- `var` isn't a valid type in Solidity. In this case, it has to be the type of the struct you are using.
- `Student student = studentsMappig[_address];` won't modify the corresponding struct because, by default, everything is done in `memory`, it's a bit like RAM. If you desire persistent changes, you need to precise you want to write to `storage` by adding the keyword : `Student storage student = studentsMappig[_address];`

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding, OP wants to save the struct into the mapping, not as an independent variable as your answer does, I added an answer to save the struct in the mapping.

Comment: wow, why are you upset? Instead of taking time to write this angry response, you could just point out why I am wrong.

Comment: Not upset. Shared a link under your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the _address in your `studentArray`. You haven't saved the student data yet. Based on @Eli's Answer you just need to modify one line:

Use `Students storage student = studentsMappig[_address];`
instead of `var student = studentsMappig[_address];`

```
contract students{

struct Students{
    string fname;
    string lname;
    string course;      
}

mapping (address => Students) studentsMappig;

address[] public studentsArray;

function setStudents(address _address, string _fname, string _lname,string _course) public{

    Students storage student = studentsMappig[_address];

    student.fname = _fname;
    student.lname = _lname;
    student.course = _course;
    studentsArray.push(_address);

}

}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Less lines != less gas. By doing what you do, it ends up more costly.

Comment: what? can you elaborate this? Your answer does not solve the problem OP want to save the structure in the mapping but you are creating a struct in the storage independently. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/44445/correct-practice-for-modifying-struct-in-mapping/44447

Comment: "You haven't saved the student data yet. " how can I store this in array in my case. i am very new in solidity and reading all answers with keen interest. Thanks

Comment: @ Malik, Eli Dirion answer is correct and mine is correct as well, however Eli's answer is cheaper in terms of gas. I modified my answer usind ELi's answer to give you the full code. This is the reason I am in this forum, to learn. I hope this will help you.